# Finding max /min value of individual columns

Tags: python, pandas, array-broadcasting

I am a beginner to Data Analysis using Python and stuck on the following:

I want to find maximum value from individual columns (pandas.dataframe) using Broadcasting /Vectorization methodology.

A snapshot of my data Frame is as follows:

[image]

Comment: I am trying to find max value using idxmax() /max() methods.

e.g- df_Close['AAPL'].max()-- This gives me max value of AAPL column.
However, when I try to pass a list of columns e.g df_Close[col_list].max(), it errors out saying 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index''

Comment: df_Close[df_Close.columns.values[col_list]].max()

Comment: You should be passing column names in the list, not an index object

Comment: Got it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you can use pandas.DataFrame built-in function max and min to find it

example

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(randn(4,4))
df.max(axis=0) # will return max value of each column
df.max(axis=0)['AAL'] # column AAL's max
df.max(axis=1) # will return max value of each row
```

or another way
just find that column you want and call max

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(randn(4,4))
df['AAL'].max()
df['AAP'].min()
```

min is the same

Comment: I was already doing it. However, I wanted to get max values of every column. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `aggregate` function to get the min and max value in a single line of code.

For the entire dataset:

`df.agg(['min', 'max'])`

For a specific column:

`df['column_name'].agg(['min', 'max'])`

Comment: In addition to being a single line of code, is using agg more efficient in terms of memory access (i.e. a single pass on the data)? It matters for large dataframes.